# NSPageController bad transition

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, transition

I have a problem with page controller transition, it looks like this

[image: bad transition]

Here is the code of my page controller

```
class PageController: NSPageController, NSPageControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        delegate = self
        arrangedObjects = ["FirstViewController", "SecondViewController"]
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any) -> String {
        return object as! String
    }

    @IBAction func forward(_ sender: Any) {
        self.navigateForward(self)
    }

    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        navigateBack(self)
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {
        return storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! NSViewController
    }

    func pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition(_ pageController: NSPageController) {
        pageController.completeTransition()
    }
}
```

Why does it look like this and what can I do to achieve normal transition?

Comment: Does the view with the labels on it have a transparent or an opaque background?

Comment: No... it's not.

Comment: it's not what? I gave two options.

Comment: It's not opaque. It's transparent.

Comment: It's ok with opaque background, but can you explain why does it behave like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you push a new page the original page is still in the view hierarchy because it has to be shown while the new page animates into view. Once the new view completely covers the original view it is removed. Because you have a transparent background on the second view, you can still see the buttons underneath.

When you push the new page off the screen, the view underneath is added to the hierarchy so you can see it as the top view animates away. Because the top view is transparent, the buttons appear before the view animates.

If you make the view opaque instead of transparent, the view underneath cannot be seen through the transparent background, so it works as you expect.